# How to execute a matrix multiplication of to 3D arrays using numpy einsum function to obtain a product matrix of 2D?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

how can I execute the following piece of code without using loop structure, instead using the numpy einsum function? I want the product matrix to be a 2D matrix and not 3D. Simply doing
"D = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',A,B)
D += np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',B,C) "  gives different result. Should I introduce any intermediate temporary array or something to use the einsum function?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [[[1, 2, 3, 0],
                 [ 4, 2, 1, 1]],
                   [[2, 0, 0, 3],
                     [1, 0, 2, 4]]] )

B = np.array( [[[0, 2, 3, 1],
                 [0, 2, 5, 0]],
                  [[0, 1, 2, 2],
                    [3, 3, 2, 1]]] )
C = np.array( [[[0, 2, 2, 1],
                 [0, 2, 1, 0]],
                  [[0, 0, 2, 0],
                    [3, 1, 2, 1]]] )
X = np.zeros([2,4])
for i in range(2):
  for j in range(2):
    for k in range(4):

        X[j,k] = A[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k]
        X[j,k] += B[i,j,k]*C[i,j,k]
D = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',A,B)
D += np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',B,C)
```

Comment: What is `C`? It isn't present in the question

Comment: Sorry David, I forgot to add the C array. Thank you for notifying me. I have updated the code now. Can you please help me?

Comment: Your `i` loop is useless, since you throw away all the `i=0` values.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to compute `X = (A*B + B*C).sum(axis = 0)`.

Comment: actually the i loop is required to specify the indices of A,B and C matrices

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, replace the `i` loop with just 1 step

```
In [64]:   X = np.zeros([2,4])
    ...:   i=1
    ...:   for j in range(2):
    ...:     for k in range(4):
    ...: 
    ...:         X[j,k] = A[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k]
    ...:         X[j,k] += B[i,j,k]*C[i,j,k]
In [65]: X
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  4.,  6.],
       [12.,  3.,  8.,  5.]])
```

This is the value as produced by your loop.  You've thrown away the `i=0` values.

But you don't need the loops to do:

```
In [68]: A[1,:,:]*B[1,:,:]+B[1,:,:]*C[1,:,:]
Out[68]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  6],
       [12,  3,  8,  5]])

In [69]: A*B+B*C
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0,  8, 15,  1],
        [ 0,  8, 10,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  4,  6],
        [12,  3,  8,  5]]])
```

The same thing with `einsum`:

```
In [71]: np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk',A,B)+np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk',B,C)
Out[71]: 
array([[[ 0,  8, 15,  1],
        [ 0,  8, 10,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  4,  6],
        [12,  3,  8,  5]]])
```

and if you want to sum across `i`:

```
In [72]: np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',A,B)+np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk',B,C)
Out[72]: 
array([[ 0,  8, 19,  7],
       [12, 11, 18,  5]])
In [73]: (A*B+B*C).sum(axis=0)
Out[73]: 
array([[ 0,  8, 19,  7],
       [12, 11, 18,  5]])
```